# Branch.io Links using the HTTP API in c#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, branch.io

I am trying to create a link via HTTP API call in our webpage but when I try to create the link. The HttpClient response is always false. I'm not sure why but I specified all necessary parameters

```
const string BranchIOUrl = "https://api.branch.io/v1/url";

            IDictionary<string, object> branchParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            IDictionary<string, string> dataParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            branchParams["$branch_key"] = "our branch key";
            branchParams["channel"] = "mobile_web";
            branchParams["feature"] = "create_link";                

            dataParams["$ios_deeplink_path"] = "value here";                                        
            dataParams["$user_profile"] = "7890";
            dataParams["$desktop_url"] = "our app link on appstore";

            branchParams["data"] = dataParams;

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BranchIOUrl);

            //Add an accept header for JSon format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(BranchIOUrl, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(branchParams));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

It looks like the issue is with this line:

```
branchParams["$branch_key"] = "our branch key";
```

The `branch_key` parameter is actually specified *without* the `$` character (I know, it's a bit confusing what belongs where). If you replace this with:

```
branchParams["branch_key"] = "our branch key";
```

you should be good to go!

Comment: I revised the branch_key already and the response is "Bad Request".

Comment: Are you URL-encoding the string? That can cause errors if there are unsafe characters

Comment: I already fixed it on two ways. (1) Thanks for your comment, I revised the "$branch_key" to "branch_key". (2) branchParams was not included on the Post request.

Comment: @Ice_Drop ahhh...totally missed that. Awesome! Would you mind updating your post with the code you ended up using, in case someone else comes across this post?